# Failed to load the sketch SVF file, [404]

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

When I try to load the SVF model, it gives me server error 404, failed to load the resource though the model is uploaded and translated, it is unable to find the SVF file of the sketch format. And it does work for other formats.

Urn of the model: 'dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6d3Rfd2hpdGluZ3R1cm5lci83LTEyLTE1JTIwSlNNLnNrcA=='

URL I'm using to load the model,
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/items/urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6d3Rfd2hpdGluZ3R1cm5lci83LTEyLTE1JTIwSlNNLnNrcA==/output/1/7-12-15%20JSM.svf

Is there any issues with Sketch file format

Viewer Javascript Code:
options.env = _viewerEnv;                // AutodeskProduction, AutodeskStaging, or AutodeskDevelopment (set in global var in this project)
    options.getAccessToken = getAccessToken;
    options.refreshToken   = getAccessToken;

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {
    loadDocument(data);   // load first entry by default
});

function loadDocument(urnStr) {

_loadedDocument = null; // reset to null if reloading
_loadedSecondaryDocument = null;

if (!urnStr || (0 === urnStr.length)) {
    alert("You must specify a URN!");
    return;
}
var fullUrnStr = "urn:" + urnStr;

Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(fullUrnStr, function(document) {
    _loadedDocument = document; // keep this in a global var so we can reference it in other spots

        // get all the 3D and 2D views (but keep in separate arrays so we can differentiate in the UX)
    _views3D = Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(document.getRootItem(), {'type':'geometry', 'role':'3d'}, true);
    _views2D = Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties(document.getRootItem(), {'type':'geometry', 'role':'2d'}, true);

    loadViewMenuOptions();                   // populate UX with views we just retrieved
    initializeViewerMain(mainViewerSelectionChanged);
    initializeViewerSecondary(secondaryViewerSelectionChanged, secondaryViewerGeometryLoaded);

        // load up first 3D view by default into the primary viewer
    if (_views3D.length > 0) {
        loadView(_loadedDocument, _viewerMain, _views3D[0]);
    }
    else {      // there weren't any 3D views!
        if (_views2D.length > 0) {
            loadView(_loadedDocument, _viewerMain, _views2D[0]);
            $('#pu_viewToLoad').val('1000'); // selects first option in 2D list
        }
        else {
            alert("ERROR: No 3D or 2D views found in this drawing!");
        }
    }
        // now load the Secondary viewer with the first 2D view by default
    if (_views2D.length > 0) {
        loadView(_loadedDocument, _viewerSecondary, _views2D[0]);
        $('#pu_viewToLoad').val('1000'); // selects first option in 2D list
    }
    else {
        console.log("WARNING: No 2D views found for secondary view, using additional 3D view");
        if (_views3D.length > 0)
            loadView(_loadedDocument, _viewerSecondary, _views3D[0]);
    }


}, function(errorCode, errorMsg) {
    alert('Load Error: ' + errorCode + " " + errorMsg);
});
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated appreciated.

Comment: what's the input you're passing for https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/ endpoint call? the viewer should receive only the URN, not the full URL path...

Comment: I am still using version 1 api, the same url loads different model format, with their respective URN.

Comment: ok, but even on the v1 you should not pass the whole URL, but only the URN of the item. Can you add part of your viewer JavaScript code to the question?

Comment: Just added the code, and i am using viewer3D.min.js

Comment: ok, the code seems correct to me... the 404 really means that the URN is not right. As I said, the URN should be only the file (the one you posted decodes to urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wt_whitingturner/7-12-15%20JSM.skp)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that's exactly my file. Can please post what URL should I use to load the model?! I cross checked the urn, it's the same. Thanks

Comment: I tried with only giving urn in the URL, still the same error. On the contrary I get the thumbnail of it but not 3D render